# SSRS to display custom text when date is blank

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating an SSRS report and I want to display custom text when a NULL date is pulled from SQL Server table.  I have used many variations but cannot to get it to display properly.  The report displays the actual dates if it is not NULL but if it is NULL it wont display anything.  Its like it almost forgets everything else you set (fill, font, bold, etc...)

The most basic statements I used are:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!Previous_Run_Date.Value),"Have not run previously",Fields!Previous_Run_Date.Value)

=IIF(Fields!Previous_Run_Date.Value Is Nothing,"Have not run previously",Fields!Previous_Run_Date.Value)
```

How can I get custom text to display when NULL, with valid dates in the DB?  Also, the Number is formatted as a custom Date: Ex: 6/20/2017

Comment: My first thought is what you allude to, the formatting removes your text.  What if you removed formatting for now and see if you get what you want? Then, in addition to setting text you also can set the format conditionally.

Comment: I have tested the first expression and works fine, either using the formatting property or not.

Comment: Have you tried IIF(Fields!Previous_Run_Date.Value = "")?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried maybe using a CASE in the dataset so the date comes in as a  custom text? Or do you need different texts for each date?

Something like this maybe?

```
    CASE WHEN Previous_Run_Date IS NULL
            THEN    'Have not run previously'
            ELSE    Previous_Run_Date
    END AS  RunDate
```